# JWT authentication concept

Tags: authentication, jwt

I am currently working on an interaction between Angular JS app and Node.js Server (as API) with an authentication based on JSON Web Token.

But I have a question I can't answer by myself : when you encode the JWT server-side putting a user as payload, how do you proceed to retrieve the user information client-side ?
Here is a small example to understand my question:

I am a basic user, I send my credentials to the API for authenticating. In exchange, I receive a JWT token but I don't have any information about the user since only the server has the secret key that is able to decode the JWT token. So does the server need to send me for example the id of the user so that I could call my api user/id for retrieving information about the user authenticated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You retrieve the user's info by decoding the token on each request.  So in your example after the token is returned to the client, the client makes a request to the server to grab the user's first and last name using the data stored in the encoded token which is sent along with the request back to the server. When making this GET request, you can send the token as a parameter.  I'll use a non-cookie stored example. Here's how it goes down:

1. The user signs in with their password and username
2. The server encodes a json web token payload that contains the unique identifier (i.e. user_id) of the user that signed in using the secret_key. An example function call may look something like this.

payload = {user_id: 35}
user_token = JWT.encode(payload, "your_secret_key");

1. Return the user_token to the client and store said token in a hidden html tag or in a localStorage variable.  Using Angular, I'd store it in localStorage.
2. Now that the user is signed_in and the token is client-side, you can submit a GET request that contains the user_token as a parameter. Remember, this user_token payload contains the user_id.
3. The server gets the parameter and decodes the user_token to get the user_id from the payload.
4. You query the database with the user_id and return the data (first and last name) as plain json, NOT ENCODED.

It's important to remember the only thing to encode in your example is the unique identifier (user_id). On each request you decode the token which itself is the authentication mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if you do so how can you use information client side. I will explain again by an example  if you are "John Doe" user and you have username jdoe and password pwd, you submit jdoe and pwd and receive a token. But how can you retrieve the information of the user that is stocked in the database like for example first and last name in order to display it in the app ?

Comment: Thanks Micah for editinng, it is clearer. I thought to it after and your answer confirms this. Thanks a lot. Good evening.

Comment: Is it true that the 'sub' (subject) key of the payload is defined by the JWT spec to be used to identify the subject of this token's claims, i.e. commonly enough this will be the place to put the user ID, rather than an arbitrary 'user_id' key. Is this so, or am I misinterpreting? (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2)

Answer (score 9):

You have the payload on the client, If your needed data is in the payload you can easily do a `Base64 Decode` on payload to find it!

To understand this here are steps:

1. Client send username:user,password:pass to server.
2. The server starts the authentication business and finds that the user name and password is valid.
3. The server must return these information back to client. Here is where `JWT` has some rules. The server must return a `token` back to client. The token has three parts `Header.PayLoad.Signature` . Forget about signature right now, which is the part which make some confusion.

The part one is `Header`. Some thing like:

```
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}
```

Which will be `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9` after `Base64 Decode`. Please consider this is just a decode, no encryption at all! To see this you can go to https://www.base64decode.org/ and test.

After the `header`, the server needs to send a payload to user. The server may decide to send below json ( I said decide, because there is no standard requirement here, you can send more or less data as payload, for example, you may also set user privileges for example `admin:true`, or user first and last name, but keep in mind that the JWT size must be small as it will be send to server on each request)

```
{"username":"user","id":3,"iat":1465032622,"exp":1465050622}
```

Again according to `JWT`, the server needs a `Base64 Decode` here ( and again no encryption at all). The above json will be `eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IjEiLCJpZCI6MywiaWF0IjoxNDY1MDMyNjIyLCJleHAiOjE0NjUwNTA2MjJ9`.

Until now the server created the `Header` and `Payload`. Now time to make signature! It is very easy:

```
var encodedString=base64UrlEncode(header) + "." + base64UrlEncode(payload);
//As our example base64UrlEncode(header) is eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
//and the base64UrlEncode(payload) is eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IjEiLCJpZCI6MywiaWF0IjoxNDY1MDMyNjIyLCJleHAiOjE0NjUwNTA2MjJ9

 var signature=HMACSHA256(encodedString, 'a secret string which is kept at server');
```

The signature is made with a secret key which you don't have it at clent!! You don't need it either. All token data is in the payload and can be accessed with decode ( again no decrypt ! ).

This signature is used at the server, when you send token back to server, the server check that signiature is correct to make sure he can trust the token data.

To summarize have a look at below token

```
//Header
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.
//PayLoad
eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IjEiLCJpZCI6MywiaWF0IjoxNDY1MDMyNjIyLCJleHAiOjE0NjUwNTA2MjJ9.
//Signature
0K8TL1YS0XKnEIfI3lYs-bu2vbWHSNZsVJkN1mXtgWg
```

Header and payloads are `Base64 Decoded` and you can encode it on client. But you can not do any thing with signature.

The signature is only used by the server. The client send each request with his token, the server must be sure that the client did not change any part of token payload (for example change userid). This is where the signature string come importance is revealed, the server recheck the signature with it's secret key for **every request**!

Note:

Do you still wonder why the JWT use encode and decode ?! To make the hole token URL safe !

Comment: If I capture someone's token then I can impersonate. What mechanism can be used to prevent this?

Comment: I think there is no mechanism in JWT. It is like session id. If you have some one session id you can impersonate.

Answer (score 6):

The strategy in the accepted answer works, but it misses the fact that *the client can see the payload of a JWT*. It is explained nicely in [The Anatomy of a JSON Web Token](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token).

A JWT has 3 parts. The first two, `header` and `payload`, are [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. The client can decode them easily. The payload has claims about the user, the client can use this data (user id, name, roles, token expiration) w/out having to make another request to the server.

The third part of the JWT is the `signature`. It is a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) of the `header`, the `payload`, and a secret that only the server knows. The server will validate the token and user's permissions on every request.

The client never knows the secret, it just has a token that claims to be the given user.

Comment: How does the client never know the secret? It needs the secret to accurately compose the token...

Comment: Or is your expectation that the server would be the only source assigning tokens payloads and headers together? That you shouldn't have clients encoding their own payloads?

Comment: @BenNelson exactly, the server is the only thing that should be generating tokens. If you let the client generate tokens, you open yourself up to attacks from malicious users b/c they would be able to generate a token with any kind of payload.

Comment: If I capture someone's token then I can impersonate. What mechanism can be used to prevent this?

Comment: @variable I don't think there is one, the same thing can happen if you can capture someone's cookies. You should always use HTTPS and set an appropriate expiration date on the JWT. But if someone can get access to the user's browser they can do whatever they want w/the cookie/JWT.