# Ionic Token authentication php Server - Security questions

Tags: php, security, ionic-framework, jwt, http-token-authentication

I'am pretty new at this topic and want to realize a token based user authentifications and wonder if that are the right steps to do this in a "pretty" secure way.

First on the Ionic App:

-> send the login data in plain text to the https server, via ionic http method

---

On the Php Server:

-> Compare username and password

-> If thats true, generate a secure key (min 25 characters)

-> Store the userid (plain) and key (MD5+Salt) in a table, with a expire time

-> Gerneate a JWT Token, with some userdata

```
JWT::encode($data, $secret);
```

-> echo the JWT Token to send it back to the ionic app

---

Back at the Ionic App:

-> Store the JWT Token in the local storage of the device

.. create some data ..

---

Send data to the php server:

-> $http post to the php server with some params

```
params: { userid : $scope.userid, jwttoken : $scope.jwttoken, datatostore: $scope.datatostore }
```

---

On the php server:

-> check if the post userid exists in the table where the keys are stored

-> if yes, get the key by filtering the userid and check if the time is not expired

-> if yes, decode the JWT

```
JWT::decode($postToken, $api_key, array('HS256', 'HS512'));
```

-> if thats success, do some server stuff like insert the data in the database

I know that there is no 100% secure way but I want to know if thats pretty save to use or if I have overseen something!

Thanks

Comment: ok i got wrong by thinking that every user needs a single secret, there can be one for all of the the jwt, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418665/maintaining-secret-key-and-access-token-for-jwt-in-express-and-nodejs-with-faceb

Comment: and good introduction http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/05/json-web-tokens-introduction/