# python fastapi how to generate new token before it expire?

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, fastapi, refresh-token

how to generate new  token before it expire? as per the fastapi doc here is the code for generate access token.

```
def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta | None = None):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=5)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt
```

here my token is expiring after 5 minutes and I want to generate another new token just before it expire .

Comment: You usually have a separate refresh token that can be used to regenerate the token _when the client needs a new token because the old one fails_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726066/jwt-refresh-token-flow