# What is secret key for JWT based authentication and how to generate it?

Tags: jwt

Recently I started working with JWT-based authentication. After the user login, a user token is generated which will look like this:

```
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ".
```

It consists of three parts each separated with a dot(.).First part is header which Base64 encoded. After decoding we will get something like:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256", //Algorithm used
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

The second part is claims and Base64 encoded. After decoding we will get something like:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true
}
```

The third part is the signature and is generated with:

```
HMACSHA256(
 base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
 base64UrlEncode(payload),
 *secret base64 encoded*
)
```

Now, what is this secret key, and how to generate this secret key?

I tried some online generators like: "http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html"

But, I didn't get much help.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

A JSON Web Token or JWT is made up of three parts:

1. The header: contains some metadata about the token itself.
2. The payload: contains the data that we want to encode into the token, so the more data we want to encode here the bigger is the JWT.
3. The signature.

These first two parts, the header and the payload, are just plain text that will get encoded, but not encrypted.

**So anyone will be able to decode them and read them**, we cannot store any sensitive data in here. But that's not a problem at all because in the third part, the signature, is where things really get interesting. The signature is created using the header, the payload, and the secret that is saved on the server.

And this whole process is then called **signing the Json Web Token**. The signing algorithm takes the header, the payload, and the secret to create a unique signature. So only this data plus the secret can create this signature.
Then together with the header and the payload, these signature forms the JWT,
which then gets sent to the client.
[image]

Once the server receives a JWT to grant access to a protected route, it needs to verify it in order to determine if the user really is who he claims to be. In other words, it will verify if no one changed the header and the payload data of the token. So again, this verification step will check if no third party actually altered either the header or the payload of the Json Web Token.

So, how does this verification actually work? Well, it is actually quite straightforward. Once the JWT is received, the verification will take its header and payload, and together with the secret that is still saved on the server, basically create a test signature.

But the original signature that was generated when the JWT was first created is still in the token, right? And that's the key to this verification. Because now all we have to do is to compare the test signature with the original signature.
And if the test signature is the same as the original signature, then it means that the payload and the header have not been modified.
[image]

Because if they had been modified, then the test signature would have to be different. Therefore in this case where there has been no alteration of the data, we can then authenticate the user. And of course, if the two signatures
are actually different, well, then it means that someone tampered with the data.
Usually by trying to change the payload. But that third party manipulating the payload does of course not have access to the secret, so they cannot sign the JWT.
So the original signature will never correspond to the manipulated data.
And therefore, the verification will always fail in this case. And that's the key to making this whole system work. It's the magic that makes JWT so simple,
but also extremely powerful.

Now let's do some practices with nodejs:

Configuration file is perfect for storing JWT SECRET data. Using the standard HSA 256 encryption for the signature, the secret should at least be 32 characters long, but the longer the better.

config.env:

```
JWT_SECRET = my-32-character-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret
//after 90days JWT will no longer be valid, even the signuter is correct and everything is matched.
JWT_EXPIRES_IN=90
```

now install JWT using command

```
npm i jsonwebtoken
```

Example after user signup passing him JWT token so he can stay logged in and get access of resources.

```
exports.signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newUser = await User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm,
  });
  const token = jwt.sign({ id: newUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      newUser,
    },
  });
});
```

output:
[image]

In my opinion, do not take help from a third-party to generate your super-secret key, because you can't say it's secret anymore. Just use your keyboard.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it contains more detailed information

Comment: It would be even more cool, If you add signature verification code block as well.

Comment: One should use a CSPRNG, not one's keyboard, to generate a secret key:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-10.1

Answer (score 75):

The algorithm (`HS256`) used to sign the JWT means that the secret is a symmetric key that is known by both the sender and the receiver. It is negotiated and distributed out of band. Hence, if you're the intended recipient of the token, the sender should have provided you with the secret out of band.

If you're the sender, you can use an arbitrary string of bytes as the secret, it can be generated or purposely chosen. You have to make sure that you provide the secret to the intended recipient out of band.

For the record, the 3 elements in the JWT are not base64-encoded but base64url-encoded, which is a variant of base64 encoding that results in a URL-safe value.

Comment: Is there a way to see this through a working example? Also it's a good point that the answer already is considered in javascript, since the question is asking about jwt.

Comment: Just a note, If you are working with JWT's you should not share your secret key with anyone, not even the receiver (which is usually user of your app)

Comment: I would never send a recipient a copy of the secret key in any circumstance. Then by that estimation they could generate their own valid key hash and forge a token themselves. The key should be secured and only known by the sender in order to validate the contents of the token when returned are valid. Also key expiration and rotation is a good practice as well.

Comment: Symmetric means more specifically that the same key is used to generate and to validate the signature. In the case of a web application, the web server is both the generator and the validator. The client is simply storing the token. Under no circumstance should you share the secret key with anyone, particularly not a user of your web app.

Comment: IMHO even tho the accepted answer has more details especially practice-wise, doesn't answer and I quote: "Now, what is this secret key, and how to generate this secret key?".
This one does! As I understand, for a symmetric algorithm, it'll be the common key (or any arbitrary byte array), and for a asymmetric one, it'll be the sender's private key which is used as secret.

Answer (score 66):

### What is the secret key

The secret key is combined with the header and the payload to create a unique hash. You are only able to verify this hash if you have the secret key.

### How to generate the key

You can choose a good, long password. Or you can generate it from a site like [this](https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm).

Example (but don't use this one now):

```
8Zz5tw0Ionm3XPZZfN0NOml3z9FMfmpgXwovR9fp6ryDIoGRM8EPHAB6iHsc0fb
```

Comment: How can you exploit a volunrability in JWT like this one where you don't know the secret key ? (example for educational purposes here: http://web.cryptohack.org/no-way-jose/)

Comment: Generating passwords online is a really, really bad idea :-) Just do it locally with `/dev/urandom` instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string

Comment: I usually use C#, and will just run Guid.NewGuid().ToString() in C# Interactive console and use the result as my secret.

Comment: Using a password as the key is a bad idea! You must use a CSPRNG:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-10.1
Using `/dev/urandom` as suggested above by @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com is good advice.

Answer (score 18):

You can write your own generator. The secret key is essentially a byte array. Make sure that the string that you convert to a byte array is base64 encoded.

In Java, you could do something like this.

```java
String key = "random_secret_key";
String base64Key = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(key.getBytes());
byte[] secretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Key);
```

Answer (score 17):

What is the secret key does, you may have already known till now.
It is basically HMAC SH256 (Secure Hash).
The Secret is a symmetrical key.

Using the same key you can generate, & reverify, edit, etc.

For more secure, you can go with private, public key (asymmetric way).
Private key to create token, public key to verify at client level.

Coming to secret key what to give
You can give anything, "sudsif", "sdfn2173", any length

you can use online generator, or manually write

I prefer using openssl

```
C:\Users\xyz\Desktop>openssl rand -base64 12
65JymYzDDqqLW8Eg
```

generate, then encode with base 64

```
C:\Users\xyz\Desktop>openssl rand -out openssl-secret.txt -hex 20
```

The generated value is saved inside the file named "openssl-secret.txt"

generate, & store into a file.

One thing is giving 12 will generate, 12 characters only, but since it is base 64 encoded, it will be (4/3*n) ceiling value.

I recommend reading this article

https://auth0.com/blog/brute-forcing-hs256-is-possible-the-importance-of-using-strong-keys-to-sign-jwts/

Comment: you could run `openssl rand <...args> | clip` to copy it to the clipboard instead of writing it to a file

Comment: Using OpenSSL's CSPRNG is a good idea, but 12 bytes, is a little bit short! Also, the Auth0 blog post is not great. The problem is not just the length of the key, but entropy. Thus a CSPRNG must be employed. A longer password is not enough. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-10.1

Answer (score 14):

For JWT, the signing algorithm [HMAC SHA256](https://jwt.io/introduction) is commonly used. For that algorithm, [32 bytes is enough](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34866).

A 32 bytes array can be expressed as a 64 characters long hexadecimal string, since 2 hexadecimal characters is equal to 1 byte. 32 random bytes, expressed as a hexadecimal string, can be generate with this terminal command:

```bash
$ openssl rand -hex 32
```

An example of what it outputs:

```
4f1feeca525de4cdb064656007da3edac7895a87ff0ea865693300fb8b6e8f9c
```

By using the command above, the key is generated locally on your computer. It can be dangerous to use a website for generating passwords, so doing it locally is preferred.

Depending on the language that you use, the next steps may differ. But in C#, you can convert the hexadecimal string to a byte array using this function:

```cs
public static byte[] FromHexStringToByteArray(string hexString) 
{
    var byteArray = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
    {
        byteArray[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

And in C#, the JWT token can then be generated in this way:

```cs
public string GenerateJwtToken(FacebookMeResponse facebookMeResponse)
{
    var issuer = "https://auth.example.com";
    var audience = "https://api.example.com";
    var expiryInMinutes = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalMinutes;
    var secretKey = "4f1feeca525de4cdb064656007da3edac7895a87ff0ea865693300fb8b6e8f9c";
    var key = FromHexStringToByteArray(secretKey);
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, issuer),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, audience),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, now.AddMinutes(expiryInMinutes).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, now.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, now.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "123"), // The user's ID
    };
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: issuer,
        audience: audience,
        claims: claims,
        expires: now.UtcDateTime.AddMinutes(expiryInMinutes),
        signingCredentials: credentials
    );
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

In the example above, the key is in the form of a hexadecimal string and is converted to a byte array. Next, an instance of `SigningCredentials` is created with the key and the algorithm set to HMAC SHA256. Later, the token is created with the credentials.

Answer (score 13):

To generate a unique secret key of say 64 bytes, run the following command in node :

```
crypto.randomBytes(64).toString("hex");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are someone looking for the secret key for the JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY then you can use any generated here:

https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

This usually for the "JWT Authentication for WP REST API"
( https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/ )

Maybe you are someone like me who got here looking for that instead :D