# How do I correctly use the sign function of the JWT module?

Tags: node.js, json, web-applications, jwt

(I am just starting out in using JWT, so sorry if I seem like a noob) I'm trying to use the 'sign' function of the jwt module. I believe the payload is valid, and as a access token secret I'm using a string. Is that all that is required?

```
payload = { name: 'adminTest', email: 'adminTest' }
```

My .env file contains this and this only:

ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET="Random string for using in TBS system"

When I try:

```
jwt.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

Is anyone able to explain why this is happening or what this error means?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309759/what-is-secret-key-for-jwt-based-authentication-and-how-to-generate-it/62095056#62095056) is good explain for JWT concept picture.