# how to prevent access file from curl use php

Tags: php, curl, jwt

Here I have a problem with curl request.

I want to block it in few files.

Here is my code on server

**MyFile.php**

```
Class MyFile {
    public function getName() {
        return "hi";
    }
    public function getBday() {
        return '01-01-1970';
    }
}

$my = New MyFile();
return json_encode($my->$_GET['functionName']());
```

localhost/test/MyFile.php?functionName=getName

Output: **hi**

localhost/test/MyFile.php?functionName=getBday

Output: **01-01-1970**

I'm running that file in **AJAX** and for security, I'm using **JWT tokens** as Authorization header in AJAX request.

That thing is working fine.

But while I try to access that file via curl from another website. then it is also responding a data. but I have to prevent it.

**AnotherServerFile.php**

```
<?php
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTk2NTA4NjMsImp0aSI6InQ4OTU3RjBIbE1yQ21UREdUdTNCK0VZdUFsTVZRZUZhNHhnckRyMzRnNXc9IiwiaXNzIjoibmlldHdhY2h0ZW4ubmwiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTk2NTA4NjMsImV4cCI6MTUxOTY1MjY2M30.wN7MA782ix-ln8uKlGNsc-oxMxJNa3hfmY9GjzhVeFhEZm5IJOMd0PU8ppUxDU9_yDGcbKsuPzNzCh6CmPQ1qA';
$header[] = "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest";
$service_url = 'localhost/test/MyFile.php?functionName=getName';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //IMP if the url has https and you don't want to verify source certificate
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($curl_response);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($response);
```

this file is on another server. like

**example.com/AnotherServerFile.php**

And **AnotherServerFile.php** file can access my **MyFile.php**'s code via cURL.

So, I want to prevent the use of **AnotherServerFile.php** accessing **MyFile.php**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So what are the exact rules of what requests are allowed and what requests are not?

Comment: @PatrickQ i want the requests only came from server. i want to restrict it from to use MyFile.php from another server

Comment: If the `AnotherServerFile` is on an other server, preventing [CORS](https://ma.ttias.be/set-access-control-allow-origin-cors-headers-apache-vhost-htaccess/) should do the job I think.

Comment: @AnthonyB No, the curl request can specify the `Origin` header.

Comment: @AnthonyB i already tried it.. but i want to prevent it from CURL

Comment: @NiravJoshi If you cannot be more specific about the requests that you want to prevent, then you're going to have a really hard time doing this.  A cURL request can easily present itself to look like a browser.  There is really nothing special about cURL requests that inherently differentiate them from any other.  If the remote server has access to your authorization tokens, then you're pretty much boned.

Comment: What about using some encryption? It's perhaps heavy, but your client will be the only one to be able to communicate with the server.

Comment: @PatrickQ So is there anything which i should make change in MyFile.php code?

Comment: @PatrickQ i m passing authorization token in ajax request as a request header. so anyone can see it. so either i have to prevent cURL or i have to pass Authorization token as some hidden manner. do you have any idea of it?

Comment: Browsers are HTTP clients. cURL is an HTTP client. You can't reliably distinguish between them. If you give a browser the information needed to successfully make a request, then the operator of that browser can do all the same things with cURL.

Comment: So, is there any other technique from where i can pass authentication header as hidden via ajax.. (can't be view by user via firebug / Inspect Element)

Comment: @NiravJoshi "so anyone can see it."  That's what SSL is for.  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf), [this](https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way#how-to-secure-jwt), [this](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/vulnerabilities) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301557/if-you-can-decode-jwt-how-are-they-secure).