# JWT token decode

Tags: php, android, jwt

I'm creating a web based mobile application. My concern is that, the payload of the JWT token can be decoded from the [JWT WEBSITE](https://jwt.io/) even without having the key. It shows **Invalid Signature** error, but still shows the payload included in the token.
I'm wondering how much secure is  using the JWT token with this scenario.
Here is a sample token generated by my API - `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKb2UiLCJuYW1lIjoidnl3diJ9.8xeKufZ-U5ksijK2fCeU7gnZ5Xg-eUTqlZ2SdxrslklHNm519xYx-0DkhEyNe2NRhMUNfyhNsnkpZWim9lqi5w`

May be my understanding about JWT is not enough, Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If you can decode JWT how are they secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301557/if-you-can-decode-jwt-how-are-they-secure)

Comment: JWT can be signed (JWS - what you mentionned in your question), encrypted (JWE - see [RFC7516](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516)) or both (signed then encrypted - in this order only).
If you need JWE support for PHP, you can have a look at https://github.com/web-token

Answer (score 0):

From the [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/) page:

> **When should you use JSON Web Tokens?**
>
> Here are some scenarios where JSON Web Tokens are useful:
>
> **Authentication:**
>
> This is the most common scenario for using JWT. Once the user is logged in, each subsequent request will include the
>   JWT, allowing the user to access routes, services, and resources that
>   are permitted with that token. Single Sign On is a feature that widely
>   uses JWT nowadays, because of its small overhead and its ability to be
>   easily used across different domains.
>
> **Information Exchange:**
>
> JSON Web Tokens are a good way of securely transmitting information between parties. Because JWTs can be
>   signed—for example, using public/private key pairs—you can be sure the
>   senders are who they say they are. Additionally, as the signature is
>   calculated using the header and the payload, you can also verify that
>   the content hasn't been tampered with.

So it is secure. You only need to verify the token with the keys and never send sensitive data (because it can be decrypted).