# Are Json Web Tokens secure enough? And how to secure payload?

Tags: cryptography, jwt

When I go to https://jwt.io I see this encoded token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

If I go to https://codebeautify.org/base64-decode , copy-paste token value and push `Decode`, I get this:

```
{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}{"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","iat":1516239022}
```

If I switch from `HS256` to `RS256`, I now get this token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.TCYt5XsITJX1CxPCT8yAV-TVkIEq_PbChOMqsLfRoPsnsgw5WEuts01mq-pQy7UJiN5mgRxD-WUcX16dUEMGlv50aqzpqh4Qktb3rk-BuQy72IFLOqV0G_zS245-kronKb78cPN25DGlcTwLtjPAYuNzVBAh4vGHSrQyHUdBBPM
```

And it also can be easily decoded with base64. So, my question is, whether it is expected behaviour or not? And if yes, what is the reason to use different algorithms (HS256, RS256 etc.), if whatever algorithm we use, we can easily read the contents using just base64 decode?

Comment: From the quick reading I have just done it seems that JWT does not intend to hide anything - it is meant to ensure integrity by adding a signature. And that signature is contained in the encoded token - but it is not shown in the decoded part that you posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If you can decode JWT how are they secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301557/if-you-can-decode-jwt-how-are-they-secure)

Comment: what you're actually seeing is a JWS, a signed token. If you really need to hide the payload, look into JWE, encrypted tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Jwt is not meant to secure the content it is used to verify a claim, ie when you sign a request using jwt, when decoding it the user/sytem must have the secret key. So to answer your question yes it is the expected behaviour, the base 64 encoding is only meant for transportation over the URL and not to secure it. The last bit if i may clarify the verification of a claim is simply to mean you are what/who you tell the system you are and that the content of the signature has not been altered even alittle bit, any changes to any part of the encoded signature will result to signature failure; hence the claim would nolonger be authentic or true. To see this just try to encode something like this in your terminal
`import jwt 
    encoded=jwt.encode({'name':'some name'}, 'somesecretkey',algorithm='HS256')`

then copy the resulting token and then remove or add asingle letter to the string and try decoding using the same secret key and watch it fail or try the same at codebeautify again