# Why JWT Token signing key is required

Tags: jwt

JWT tokens required signing key to decode them, but in https://jwt.io/ it can be decoded without any signing key, how is this possible.

Comment: No, the signing key is not required to decode, but it is required to verify the signature. And your services must not ever use a jwt without verifying its signature.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301557/if-you-can-decode-jwt-how-are-they-secure?rq=1

Comment: the key is used to sign the token or to verify the signature of an existing token. The header and payload can easily be decoded, they're just Base64Url encoded.

Comment: Some nitpicking: the "T" in JWT stands for "token", so writing JWT token is redundant.

Comment: Notice that "verify signature" block in jwt.io - that's where your signing key comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a key to open the encoding, you need a key to verify that nobody changed the contents of the JWT. In fact the string you see is just json's base64 with your information, metadata, and "signature" on all content.

The signature is the most important part of a JSON Web Token(JWT). A signature is calculated by encoding the header and payload using Base64url Encoding and concatenating them with a period separator. Which is then given to the cryptographic algorithm.

```
// signature algorithm
data = base64urlEncode( header ) + “.” + base64urlEncode( payload )
signature = HMAC-SHA256( data, secret_salt )
```

So when the header or payload changes, the signature has to calculated again. Only the Identity Provider(IdP) has the private key to calculate the signature which prevents the tampering of token.

read more:

https://medium.com/@sureshdsk/how-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-works-585c4f076033
https://jwt.io/introduction/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Q17ubqLfaM

Comment: And the receiving end either has the public key to be able to decode and verify locally or invokes a url on the identity provider to do the actual signature verification.