# How do you authenticate through a C# Post API and then store the cookies I receive from a successful login

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-2.2, z-wave

I'm building a web api app which will ping a remote server with form data and the response will return two cookies which I will need to authenticate all future Get and Post methods. I'm an apprentice so I want to do this the best way possible but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JWT** (JSON Web Token)  https://jwt.io/

Send Token to user After login And then use that same Token For all the future Calls

Firstly Understand the Concept of JWT From this link.
[JWT authentication concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392562/jwt-authentication-concept)

Example Link

http://www.decatechlabs.com/secure-webapi-using-jwt

[JWT authentication for ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api)